# Search custom Playa fields with Super Search using template parameters

Tags: playa, supersearch

Using Super Search 2.0.7, I want to be able to search on a custom Playa field using the `results` template tag.

```
{exp:super_search:results
    channel       = "entries"
    keywords      = "something"
    cf_city       = "Boston"
    dynamic       = "off"
}
    {super_search_total_results}
{/exp:super_search:results}
```

I can get this to work perfectly fine using GET params:

```
/search&keywords=something&cf_city=Boston&channel=entries
```

Am I missing something to get this functionality working with template tag params?

Answer (score 2):

You need to make sure the field is set to "searchable" in the field settings page but you should be able to get the two working together.

> Super Search has limited support for Pixel & Tonic's Playa add-on. You
>   can perform regular searches (excluding exact, ranges, etc) on entry
>   titles within Playa fields, as long as the field(s) are set to
>   searchable in the custom fields' settings. This means that you are be
>   able to perform direct searches on Playa fields, as well as keyword
>   searches that include Playa field searching.

Comment: Thank you for taking the time to answer. My Playa field is indeed set to "searchable". Note - I can get this to work with GET params (rather than template params) however that is not what I am trying to do.

Comment: What if you just remove the `keyword` parameter (and it's value) from the super_search tag. I know you may need this in there but just to test for the time being to see if that works.